# geopandas has no attribute clip

Tags: python, gis, polygon, geopandas, clipping

I'm trying to clip a points from a GeoDataFrame to a polygon I've isolated from another GeoDataFrame. Eventually I'd like to build this into a loop and clip everything at once, but right now a single clip isn't running on either a GeoSeries containing one geometry or the entire GeoDataFrame. I've tried updating my packages and reinstalling them - not sure if this is a functional error I'm not seeing:

```
    geo = geopandas.read_file("fz....shx") #has a series of polygon geometries 
    geo.crs = "EPSG:4326"

    df = pd.read_csv("cleanedMCD...csv"). #has a series of points (lat, lon) 

    gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.lat, df.lon))
    gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"

    mask = geo.loc[0] #grab the first polygon from geo

    zoneGeo = geopandas.clip(gdf, mask)
```

Yields the following error:

```
    AttributeError: module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'clip'
```

Comment: You need GeoPandas 0.7 to use `clip`. You likely have older version.